# Serve two SPA applications on Nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, single-page-application, nginx-config, serve

### I try to serve two angular applications through nginx in local

I have the following folder structure:

```
/html/page1

/html/page2
```

Inside each folder are contained the files of each application.

Inside **page1**:

```
3rdpartylicenses.txt
favicon.ico
index.html
main.14de877820428b623cf2.js
polyfills.f4b78b65941f8063fd57.js
runtime.06daa30a2963fa413676.js
styles.22f686fc418e8e8e0c6e.css
```

Inside **page2**:

```
3rdpartylicenses.txt
favicon.ico
index.html
main.275a9dc67ff328ee34fa.js
polyfills.4ea17e55c619d6f4aaad.js
runtime.b57bf819d5bdce77f1c7.js
styles.f7757684f1abbaee3fb9.css
```

And this is my **nginx.confg**

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;


        location /page1{
            alias   html/page1;
            $uri $uri/ $uri/index.html /page1/index.html html/page1/index.html index.html
        }

        location /page2{
            alias   html/page2;
            $uri $uri/ $uri/index.html /page2/index.html html/page2/index.html index.html
        }


        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }

}
```

> when I try to access to http://localhost/page2/ or http://localhost/page2/ I get a blank page

In the console I see the errors:

> GET http://localhost/styles.f7757684f1abbaee3fb9.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) 
>   GET http://localhost/runtime.b57bf819d5bdce77f1c7.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>   GET http://localhost/styles.f7757684f1abbaee3fb9.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>   GET http://localhost/runtime.b57bf819d5bdce77f1c7.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

But if I run the URL http://localhost/page1/runtime.b57bf819d5bdce77f1c7.js I get the file without any problem.

I have tried numerous ways for the `try_files`. I think the problem lies in that line.

the `/location` folders works well, if I put static index files they work normally.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The console show you that the URIs are being requested without the `/page1` or `/page2` prefix, so the locations do not match. Either fix the `index.html` file to load the resources from the correct URI or add a `location /` block that tries to find the files in either directory.

Comment: @RichardSmith I can not change the index, it is autogenerated by the angular build, I tried to put a location / block like this: `location / {
   alias html;
   try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.html;
        }` But I get the same errors.

Comment: It's not a scalable solution, but this should work: `location / { root html; try_files /page1$uri /page2$uri =404; }`

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you very much!  @RichardSmith  But now I have a new problem, when I refresh the page from some internal tab, I have 404 error, is there any solution for this?

Comment: @RichardSmith `GET /pedidos HTTP/1.1 404 555 "-"`

Comment: Going back to my original comment, I think you need to fix index.html. Maybe use the `--base-href` option with the angular build?

Comment: yass,  I've done the build with --base-href and now it works correctly, thanks @RichardSmith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following configuration would be needed in the **nginx.conf** file:

```
location / { 
      root html; 
      try_files /page1$uri /page2$uri =404; 
}

location /page1{
      alias   html/page1;
      try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.html /page1/index.html;
}

location /page1{
      alias   html/page2;
      try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.html /page2/index.html;
 }
```

In addition to these configurations we must create folders with the name page1 and page1 inside the html directory of nginx.

And also when doing the application build, apply the `--base-href` parameter with the name of the folder where it will be contained in the following way:

`ng build --prod --base-href / page1`

`ng build --prod --base-href / page2`